# How to set SpaProxyServerUrl based on environment in .net core 6

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, single-page-application

In the SPA project Angular 13 with Asp.net Core 6. I want to set the SpaProxyServerUrl based on the environments like Dev, Stage and Prod. In the csproj file i have the code as below.
Can we able to set the property "SpaProxyServerUrl" in program.cs file or is there any way to set the value dynamically based on the environment?

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
    <SpaProxyServerUrl>http://localhost:4200</SpaProxyServerUrl>
    <SpaProxyLaunchCommand>npm start</SpaProxyLaunchCommand>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Can [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/intro?view=aspnetcore-7.0#setup-for-the-client-app) help you? `The following highlighted code from ClientApp/proxy.conf.js uses logic based on the environment variables set during development to determine the port the backend is running on:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself. Using "Choose" tag we can set SpaProxyServerUrl value as below

```
<Choose>
        <When Condition="'$(EnvironmentName)' == 'dev'">
            <PropertyGroup>
                <SpaProxyServerUrl>https://localhost:4200</SpaProxyServerUrl>
            </PropertyGroup>
        </When>
        <When Condition="'$(EnvironmentName)' == 'poc'">
            <PropertyGroup>
                <SpaProxyServerUrl>https://localhost:4201</SpaProxyServerUrl>
            </PropertyGroup>
        </When>
</Choose>
```